# When i use set( list_a + list_b ) it returns a dictionary. Do sets naturally return dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

I'm doing some beginner python exercises and one of them is to remove duplicates from a list.  I've successfully done it, but the strange thing is that it is returning a dictionary instead of a list.

This is my code.

```
import random  

a = []  
b = []  

for i in range(0,20):  
    n = random.randint(0,10)  
    a.append(n)  

for i in range(0,20):  
    n = random.randint(0,10)  
    b.append(n)  

print(sorted(a))  
print(sorted(b))  

c = set(list(a+b))  

print(c) 

and this is what it's spitting out

[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]  
[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]  
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

---

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but the third (final) print output doesn't look like a dictionary to me.  There are only values, not keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

`{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}` is a set, not a dictionary, a dictionary would be printed as `{key:value, key:value, ...}`

Try `print(type(c))` and you'll see it prints `<class 'set'>` rather than `<class 'dict'>`

Also try the following

```
s = {1,2,3}
print(type(s))

d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
print(type(d))
```

You'll see the type is different